# Export option "opposite" to `H`

Tags: org-mode, org-export

In the org manual one finds the `H` option for exporting. It says

```
H:
Set the number of headline levels for export (org-export-headline-levels). ...
```

**Q**: Is there an export option for setting the initial level for export?

I'd like to skip the first level when exporting.